# How can i set the initial value of a form to be html or Template Language in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have this form, where i set the `MyField` value to be non-editable, so that it can be sent to my database without being edited by the user. I want the default value to be retrieved from my db.

Basically each page is an `item`. All the`items` are stored in a `market` table on my database. Each item has a corresponding page: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/market/item/`. In the form, i need the `item` value to be sent to the database without being edited by the user.

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):

    MyField = forms.CharField(
        initial="{{market.item}}",
        disabled=True,
        widget=forms.TextInput)
```

The view:

```
def myview(request):
    item = get_object_or_404(market, item=item)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = MyForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            send = form.save()
            send.save()
            messages.success(request, f"Success")
    else:
        form = MyForm()

    return render(request,
                  "main/mytemplate.html",
                  context={"form":form})
```

Comment: There are a few misunderstandings here. But mainly, if you don't want the value to be edited by the user, why put it in the form at all?

Comment: I think you can give the default value for your field in your model

Comment: @DanielRoseman essentially because i would not know how to do that in any other way. I can't do it in the model, since the value that should be initial depends on the page that the user landed on, and it's not a fixed value

Comment: Which is why you do it in the view. Show the view code. And explain exactly what "value" is supposed to be.

Comment: I edited the question, i hope it's a bit easier to understand now

Comment: But you didn't describe what `market` is supposed to be or where it is coming from.

Comment: it's just a table containing all the items

Comment: Argh. Where is the *specific* value you want to insert in the form coming from? How are you identifying which value you want from the table?

Comment: @DanielRoseman it's defined in the view, take a look to the second line

Comment: @Jack022, I think what Daniel is asking, is _which_ market record are you wanting it to default to. One assumes the Market table has multiple records.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the way to do this is *not* to make it as part of the form at all.

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
         model = MyModel
         exclude = ['MyField']
```

Now you set it on save:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = MyForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        send = form.save(commit=False)
        send.MyField = market.item
        send.save()
        messages.success(request, f"Success")
        return redirect('/')  # always redirect after a successful post
```

Comment: I understand! Just one thing, what is the exclude part for?

Answer (score 1):

I think there's some confusion here.

You can set as follows:

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):

    MyField = forms.CharField(
        default="909",
        editable=False,
        widget=forms.TextInput)
```

And this will prevent the field from being edited, and default a value of 909 into it.

I'm unclear if this fully answers your question or not though, as I'm not sure I fully understand what you want to do.

Comment: Hey! I edited the question, i hope it's easier to undestand now, i know it sounds a bit complicated

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this:

```
def myview(request,item):
    item = get_object_or_404(market, item=item)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = MyForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            send = form.save(commit=False)
            send.MyField = item
            send.save()
            messages.success(request, f"Success")
            return redirect('redirect where you want')
    else:
        form = MyForm()

    return render(request,
                  "main/mytemplate.html",
                  context={"form":form})
```